# Using WordPress as piecemeal in existing site?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

After some solid advice from people on here about using WordPress for a small (six page) website, I wanted to broach another question regarding using WordPress for a non-blogging site.  Yet, I know my client would like to update various, but small portions of their site from time-to-time.

I won't be installing WP in the root, but a sub-directory and have all my core site files sitting in the root.

Here are my questions:

1. Can I include content from Pages in WordPress and output that content on any page outside of the WP install directory?  Is there something specific I would need to include?
2. Do I have to use a Theme or can I still use my already built CSS?
3. I'd like to be able to use my own CSS for the site and not have it be tied to a Theme - is that possible?  Meaning I use www.example.com/css/styles.css vs www.example.com/wp-content/themes/styles.css.
4. I also have a slider comprised of three DIVs for each panel, can I pull in that specific Page with that markup for the slider?
5. Can I also make my own queries for data as well?
6. Is there anything that I won't be able to accomplish or advise against doing?

I'm mostly concerned about having to use a Theme, mostly because I don't know if I'll need to use it or not.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might want to consider asking this on the [Wordpress-specific StackExchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Lots of docs available:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Giving_WordPress_its_Own_Directory_While_Leaving_the_WordPress_Index_File_in_the_Root_Directory

and

http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website , where you pull pages/posts from the WP loop into your existing design, CSS, etc.

You will need to link necessary JS files in the site.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts will show you how to make your own queries.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I won't be pulling posts, just Pages.

I'm confused by what you mean, "You will need to link necessary JS files in the site."